# How to change product code of msi using powershell?

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer

We are having Wix based msi and Install shield based Msi. For wix based msi , I have changed the product code in Wxs file thus the product code is changed as per my need.

But for installshield msi , I could not do like that. I explored Iscmdbld.exe for option to change product code but no help.

Some blogs says about using Wix 4.0 'WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller.dll'. But i am not finding this assembly with Wix 3.10.3.

Is there any other way i can update the product code using powershell?

Comment: That sounds like something you could use [Orca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx) for.

Comment: What are you trying to gain from changing the product code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in WiX 3.10.3 this library calls Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll.
 Highly likely you have seen this  [article](http://www.laurierhodes.info/?q=node/104) which shows how to edit MSI with help of PowerShell and WiX library, just use Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller from 3.10.3 instead of WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller.
 Here is a script which changes MSI ProductCode:

```
#Copy dll from WiX binary files (version 3.10.3) 

# Add Required Type Libraries
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"

# Open an MSI Database
$oDatabase = New-Object Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Database("C:\Temp\Bliss_LP_net.msi", [Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.DatabaseOpenMode]::Direct);

#Create a Select Query against an individual property
$sSQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property= 'ProductCode'"

#Create and Execute a View object
[Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.View]$oView = $oDatabase.OpenView($sSQLQuery)
$oView.Execute()

#Fetch the Result
$oRecord = $oView.Fetch()
$sProductCode = $oRecord.GetString(2)

#Display Retrieved Field
"ProductCode = $($sProductCode)"

#Generate new random guid 
$newProductCode = "{$((New-Guid).guid)}"
"newProductCode = $($newProductCode)"  

$oRecord.SetString("Value",$newProductCode)
$oView.Modify([Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.ViewModifyMode]::Update,$oRecord)

#Close the Database
$oView.Close();
$oDatabase.Dispose();
```

Comment: While this seems to work, I was disappointed when running msi package with updated ProductCode because I thought it would help me skip Change/Repair buttons and allow me to run the complete setup again.